# WCF Callback address dictionary with Load Balancing

Tags: wcf, dictionary, callback, load-balancing

Current Environment
We are using Publisher/subscriber model using WCF callbacks. We have WCF service hosted in IIS on a single Web server. Any client can subscribe/unsubscribe by calling service methods and we save/remove callback address respectively with client ID in dictionary i.e.,

PrivateShared _currentSubscribers As New Dictionary(Of UShort, ICallbackService)()

Dictionary is static member and is used across the web application (in memory not persistent)

New Environment
We are shifting our websites to new servers now. We will have two servers hosting the service with load balancer in between.

Now we need to figure out that how we are going to maintain list of subscriber which can be available on both servers. Certainly, we can’t use the same in memory dictionary in this scenario. 
We are searching for any method in which we can share dictionary among the servers.

We have tried saving in db but its not serializable or usable on other server.

We have spend some good time in searching but didn't find any solution for this in which we can share callback address among servers.

Can someone guide us on how we can acheive this? or any other option that we can use?

I would be really thankful to you for your help. Waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 2):

The key to your solution is probably at the client side.

See, no matter what, you client should be aware that your connection can get severed, at any time. So, if it handles this, and can automatically recover from it, then it has no problem connecting to a farm of N servers or of 1 server, because it simply doesn't know the difference.

Therefore, you don't NEED to have the client connected to both (i.e. "all") servers, it only needs to maintain a connection to one of them. This is course means that, given that people use load balancing to balance load rather than to simply provide redundancy, you run the chance of having one machine serve way more than half of your active connections.

But again, your client doesn't know that. So, your server could cut the cord every so often, on purpose, if nothing else than to make the client bounce (potentially) from one server to another, constantly spreading out the load. Your client should be resilient to disconnects anyway, again, it won't know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share that callback dictionary between servers. Each server must have its own dictionary maintaining its own clients and because of that you must use load balancing algorithm with session affinity (sticky sessions). This algorithm will forward all requests from single client to the same server.